# There's these white glitches in object mode when I turn on viewport shading. How do I fix this?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, shaders

[image]

This is what I see. I see these white lines around it. I am very new to blender and I am doing a donut tutorial. I don't know if this is normal or not.

Comment: Hmm this is either bad topology with way too sharp edges or inverted normals... Try to go to edit mode, select all faces and press Alt+N and select Recalculate Outside... If it won't help, please give as better view of your topology from closeup

Comment: or please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/